# raster::overlay with a function that calls a list of vectors

Tags: r, raster

I wonder if it’s possible to use overlay function of raster package with a function that calls a list of vectors to perform some calculations based on two rasters. So far I just saw examples of functions performing some raster algebra without calling external data.

Hereafter I provide some toy code to illustrate what I’m trying to do, but can also provide some context on my real problem. Specifically, I need to classify each pixel as either zero (absence) or one (presence) of housings. The likelihood of housing presence is related to the percentage of built-up area covering the pixel (raster ‘r1’ below), and the land cover type (raster ‘r2’ below). This likelihood is known based on reference data, which is stored in a list like ‘probs’ below.

```
library(raster)

# continuous and categorical maps
r1<-r2<-raster()
r1[]<-round(runif(ncell(r1))*100)
r2[]<-1
r2[1:30000]<-2

# probability of housing presence in each stratum
prob1<-1:100/100 
prob2<-log(1:100)/max(log(1:100))

# list of probabilities to be used in overlay
probs<-list(prob1,prob2)

# overlay - not working
o<-overlay(r1,r2,fun=function(x,y,...){return(rbinom(n=1, size=1, prob=probs[[y]][x]))})
```

the error is

> cannot use this formula, probably because it is not vectorized

Alternatively to the toy code above, I thought to process each categorical class separately and use function calc rather than function overlay (see below). However, this is extremely slow (if not impossible) for large rasters, so I though overlay would be better.

```
# alternative: loop across categorical classes (extremely slow for large rasters)
r<-list()
for(i in 1:2){
  stratum<-r2
  stratum[Which(stratum !=i)]<-NA
  r[[i]]<-calc(r1, fun=function(x,...){return(rbinom(n=1, size=1, prob=probs[[i]][x]))})
  r[[i]]<-mask(r[[i]],stratum)
}

r<-stack(r)
r<-sum(r,na.rm=T)

par(mfrow=c(1,3))
plot(r1)
plot(r2)
plot(r)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I ran into this same error recently. My solution was to "Vectorize" the function that is passed to overlay. This creates a wrapper of your function with mapply so that overlay can use it. I was able to get your code to run by using Vectorize (see below).

```
library(raster)
# continuous and categorical maps
r1<-r2<-raster()
r1[]<-round(runif(ncell(r1))*100)
r2[]<-1
r2[1:30000]<-2

# probability of housing presence in each stratum
prob1<-1:100/100 
prob2<-log(1:100)/max(log(1:100))

# list of probabilities to be used in overlay
probs<-list(prob1,prob2)

## edits below
# define function
f <- function(x,y,...){return(rbinom(n=1, size=1, prob=probs[[y]][x]))}

# run function using overlay with Vectorize
o <- overlay(r1,r2,fun=Vectorize(f))
```

This produced a raster layer of probabilities. It also produced the following error:

> In rbinom(n = 1, size = 1, prob = probs[[y]][x]) : NAs produced

I am not sure if this error would be problematic with your real data.

You can also refer to the second answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452135/thornthwaite-evapotranspiration-on-a-raster-dataset-error-formula-not-vectoris/51643106#51643106) for another worked example.

Comment: Thank you @masterfan. Vectorize works well for the toy data. For my real data, things are not that simple, and actually I have to deal with some issues such that error you mentioned. Let's what I can do. Thanks a lot.