# Vectorizing function which calls a dataframe for use in raster::overlay()

Tags: r, stack, vectorization, overlay, raster

I have a function which alters a RasterLayer given conditions specified in a dataframe. I would like to call this function using the overlay() function to alter a RasterStack but am having trouble vectorizing my function.

Here is an example of what I am doing with dummy data:

```
library(raster)
library(dplyr)

#generate dummy dataframe
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=3,ncol=43))
colnames(df) <- c("date_start", "date_end", "pixel_id")
df$date_start <- seq(as.Date("2024-01-01"), as.Date("2024-01-03"), by="+1 day")
df$date_end <- seq(as.Date("2024-02-01"), as.Date("2024-02-03"), by="+1 day")
df$pixel_id <- c(1,2,3)

#generate raster with pixel ids
id_raster <- raster(nrow=3, ncol=3, xmn=-123, xmx=-121, ymn=43, ymx=45) %>% setValues(seq(1,9))

#make a raster stack for editing
stackable <- id_raster / id_raster # make one blank raster
daylist <- seq(as.Date("2024-01-01"), as.Date("2024-02-03"), by="+1 day")
stack <- stack(replicate(length(daylist), stackable)) %>% setZ(daylist) # make a stack of rasters with one layer for every day of interest

#set function to apply to each layer
fun <- function(layer, id_raster,...) {
    day <- getZ(layer)
    day_data <- df %>% filter(date_start <= as.Date(day)) %>% filter(date_end >= as.Date(day))
    new_layer <- Which((id_raster %in% day_data$pixel_id), na.rm=F, cells=F)
    new_layer <- new_layer + layer
    return(new_layer)}

#use overlay to apply my function to each layer of the stack
new_stack <- overlay(stack, id_raster, fun=Vectorize(fun))
```

When I run this, the final line returns the error: "cannot use this formula, probably because it is not vectorized." So I assume I am using the Vectorize() function incorrectly somehow.

[This question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51762846/rasteroverlay-with-a-function-that-calls-a-list-of-vectors) gets close to mine but the function calls on a list while mine calls on a dataframe. Somehow this must make a difference because simply using the Vectorize() call isn't working for me like it did for them.

I have tried adding a vectorize.args argument to the Vectorize() call using various syntaxes but I either still get the same error or my code seems to run endlessly (which shouldn't happen with such a small dataset).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I do not think this can be easily done with `raster::overlay`. I show a more direct way using "terra", as that package has replaced "raster".

Your example data

```
df <- data.frame(matrix(nrow=3,ncol=3))
colnames(df) <- c("date_start", "date_end", "pixel_id")
df$date_start <- seq(as.Date("2024-01-01"), as.Date("2024-01-03"), by="+1 day")
df$date_end <- seq(as.Date("2024-02-01"), as.Date("2024-02-03"), by="+1 day")
df$pixel_id <- c(1,2,3)

library(terra)
id_raster <- rast(nrow=3, ncol=3, xmin=-123, xmax=-121, ymin=43, ymax=45, vals=1:9)

s <- rast(id_raster, nlyr=34, vals=1)
time(s) <- seq(as.Date("2024-01-01"), as.Date("2024-02-03"), by="+1 day")
```

Solution

```
days <- time(s)
out <- lapply(1:nlyr(s), \(i) {
            d <- days[i]
            ids <- df$pixel_id[df$date_start <= d & df$date_end >= d]
            if (length(ids) > 0) {
                m <- subst(id_raster, ids, 1, NA)
                mask(s[[i]], m)
            } else { 
                NULL 
            }
        })

x <- sum(rast(out), na.rm=TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks so much! This absolutely answers my question. For a stack of dim(181 x 186 x 365) your lapply() call took 140 seconds. I think Umar's use lapply() (with my original function) is slightly faster but I'm excited about exploring the capabilities of SpatRasters and terra() with your method. Accepting this answer because it requires no edits while Umar's required a few small ones.

Comment: Also--I just wanted to say I'm an undergraduate student writing a thesis on species distribution modeling and found your and Jane Elith's SDM tutorial so so helpful (as well as the threshold() function you wrote with Diego Nieto-Lugilde)!! I genuinely feel honored to have your feedback on my Stack question!

Answer (score 0):

```
# Modified function to accept filtered dataframe
fun <- function(layer, id_raster, day_data) {
  new_layer <- which(id_raster[] %in% day_data$pixel_id, arr.ind = TRUE)
  layer[new_layer] <- layer[new_layer] + 1
  return(layer)
}

# Apply function using calc
new_stack <- calc(stack, fun = function(x) fun(x, id_raster, df))

x <- sum(new_stack, na.rm = TRUE)
```

Comment: Thanks for this answer, Umar! It runs alright for me! The only issue is that I need to create a different filtered dataframe for each layer based on the z-value (date) for each layer. Maybe I'm not understanding how calc and/or overlay work correctly, but is there a way to getZ() for the layer in question and make a new filtered dataframe from that for each function call?

Comment: I added new reponse, can u check,if it is correct

Answer (score 0):

Hows about this one, is it correct

```
library(raster)
library(dplyr)

# Generate dummy data
df <- data.frame(
  date_start = seq(as.Date("2024-01-01"), as.Date("2024-01-03"), by = "day"),
  date_end = seq(as.Date("2024-02-01"), as.Date("2024-02-03"), by = "day"),
  pixel_id = c(1, 2, 3)
)

id_raster <- raster(nrow = 3, ncol = 3, xmn = -123, xmx = -121, ymn = 43, ymx = 45) %>% setValues(seq(1, 9))

# Pre-filter dataframe for efficiency
filtered_dfs <- lapply(daylist, function(day) {
  df %>% filter(date_start <= as.Date(day), date_end >= as.Date(day))
})

# Modified function to accept filtered dataframe
fun <- function(layer, day_data) {
  day <- getZ(layer)
  day_df <- day_data[[as.character(day)]]
  pixel_ids <- day_df$pixel_id
  new_layer <- layer
  new_layer[id_raster[] %in% pixel_ids] <- new_layer[id_raster[] %in% pixel_ids] + 1
  return(new_layer)
}

# Apply function using lapply
new_stack_list <- lapply(1:nlayers(stack), function(i) fun(stack[[i]], filtered_dfs))

# Convert the list to a RasterStack
new_stack <- stack(new_stack_list)

#sum function on the resulting RasterStack:
x <- sum(new_stack, na.rm = TRUE)
```

also u can try by replacing whith your function here such as

```
fun <- function(layer, day_data) {
  day <- getZ(layer)
  day_data <- df %>% filter(date_start <= as.Date(day)) %>% filter(date_end >= as.Date(day))
  new_layer <- Which((id_raster %in% day_data$pixel_id), na.rm=F, cells=F)
  new_layer <- new_layer + layer
  return(new_layer)
}
```

and rest will be same

Comment: I haven't gotten the filtered dataframe technique to work (the day_df <- day_data[[as.character(day)]] call returns NA for me but if it did work the day_df doesn't include pixel_ids). However, your lapply method works with my function! For a stack of dim(181 x 186 x 365) the lapply() call took 75 seconds. I haven't figured out why, but the result is doubled (e.g. a matching pixel_id is assigned a vaue of 2 rather than 1)... but this can be easily fixed with some Raster math. Thanks so much, Umar!!