# Calculating Thornthwaite Evapotranspiration on Raster Data more efficiently

Tags: r, raster, zoo, terra

I'm currently running Thornthwaite Evapotranspiration calculation for huge raster stacks. I'm following a solution by Robert Hijmans from another stack overflow thread: [Thornthwaite evapotranspiration on a raster dataset . Error formula not vectorised](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50452135/thornthwaite-evapotranspiration-on-a-raster-dataset-error-formula-not-vectoris)

The short reproducible example from said thread is as follows:

```
library(SPEI)
library(raster)
library(zoo)

tm = array(20,c(3,4,12*64))
tm = brick(tm)

dates=seq(as.Date("1950-01-01"), as.Date("2013-12-31"), by="month")
tm<- setZ(tm,dates)
names(tm) <- as.yearmon(getZ(tm))

#thornthwaite ET
th <- function(Tave, lat) {
    as.vector(SPEI::thornthwaite(as.vector(Tave), lat))
} 

a <- raster(tm)
lat <- init(a, "y")
#out <- raster::overlay(tm, lat, fun = th)
out <- brick(tm, values=FALSE)

for (i in 1:ncell(tm)) {
    out[i] <- th(tm[i], lat[i])
}
```

The problem, however, is that the cell-wise calculation of Thornthwaite PET seems rather inefficient, and therefore I strive for a solution using overlay or calc which I assume promises more computational efficiency. In the aforementioned stackoverflow thread another solution using overlay was introduced - however, I fail to reproduce it.

Any solution potentially increasing computational efficiency would be very welcome!

Answer (score 0):

The efficiency of either approach depends on whether you have a greater number of cells per grid or more layers, essentially dictated by your region of interest and spatial resolution, as well as the period or temporal resolution under investigation. Both methods could be viable, but their suitability varies depending on the specific circumstances, in my opinion.

However, in the referenced question, @mastefan appeared quite confident that he had managed to fix @Robert Hijmans approach. However, this exchange took place in 2018, and I have been unable to replicate the solution myself. Therefore, I decided to attempt using the 2018 version of the {SPEI} package available on CRAN (and probably I should have also used the legacy versions of `{raster}` and `{zoo}` to ensure consistency in results, but you get the idea for now...):

```r
url <- "https://cran.r-project.org/src/contrib/Archive/SPEI/SPEI_1.7.tar.gz"
install.packages(url, repos = NULL, type = "source")
```

Let's run the code (and please forgive me for not reiterating all initialization and pre-processing steps):

```r
raster::overlay(tm, lat, fun = Vectorize(th))
#> class      : RasterBrick 
#> dimensions : 3, 4, 12, 768  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#> resolution : 0.25, 0.3333333  (x, y)
#> extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA 
#> source     : memory
#> names      :  layer.1,  layer.2,  layer.3,  layer.4,  layer.5,  layer.6,  layer.7,  layer.8,  layer.9, layer.10, layer.11, layer.12, layer.13, layer.14, layer.15, ... 
#> min values : 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, ... 
#> max values : 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, ...
```

Great, this is now executable.  It appears that the behavior of `SPEI::thornthwaite()` may have changed since 2018. However, let's examine the execution speed as you expressed concerns about efficiency:

```r
mbm <- microbenchmark::microbenchmark("raster::overlay()" = raster::overlay(tm, lat, fun = Vectorize(th)),
                                      "cell-wise loop" = for (i in 1:ncell(tm)) {
                                        
                                        out[i] <- th(tm[i], lat[i])
                                      }, 
                                      times = 100)
mbm
#> Unit: milliseconds
#>               expr       min        lq     mean    median        uq      max neval
#>  raster::overlay() 7694.4259 7865.7535 8040.483 7995.6493 8126.7056 9043.048   100
#>    cell-wise loop  102.5918  106.5566  116.190  114.4493  121.6464  171.598   100
```

The execution speed doesn't seem to be faster; in fact, it appears significantly slower. However, to be fair, I'm not very familiar with `{raster}`, so perhaps someone more experienced could have optimized this quite easily. My intention was to profile these code snippets as they are. Additionally, it's worth noting that `{terra}` would likely be the preferred package choice in 2024.

However, what worries me more are the differing results from both approaches. Perhaps we should prioritize obtaining accurate results over maximizing speed.

```r
out1 <- raster::overlay(tm, lat, fun = Vectorize(th))
out1
#> class      : RasterBrick 
#> dimensions : 3, 4, 12, 768  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#> resolution : 0.25, 0.3333333  (x, y)
#> extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA 
#> source     : memory
#> names      :  layer.1,  layer.2,  layer.3,  layer.4,  layer.5,  layer.6,  layer.7,  layer.8,  layer.9, layer.10, layer.11, layer.12, layer.13, layer.14, layer.15, ... 
#> min values : 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, 125.1804, ... 
#> max values : 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, 125.5248, ...
```

```r
out2 <- raster::brick(tm, values = FALSE)

for (i in 1:ncell(tm)) {
  
  out2[i] <- th(tm[i], lat[i])
}

out2
#> class      : RasterBrick 
#> dimensions : 3, 4, 12, 768  (nrow, ncol, ncell, nlayers)
#> resolution : 0.25, 0.3333333  (x, y)
#> extent     : 0, 1, 0, 1  (xmin, xmax, ymin, ymax)
#> crs        : NA 
#> source     : memory
#> names      :  layer.1,  layer.2,  layer.3,  layer.4,  layer.5,  layer.6,  layer.7,  layer.8,  layer.9, layer.10, layer.11, layer.12, layer.13, layer.14, layer.15, ... 
#> min values : 76.06896, 68.79146, 76.29749, 73.89062, 76.37712, 73.92394, 76.38355, 76.36436, 73.87383, 76.21108, 73.64047, 76.04259, 76.06896, 68.79146, 76.29749, ... 
#> max values : 76.27825, 68.91329, 76.32396, 73.97994, 76.56333, 74.14654, 76.59547, 76.49955, 73.89596, 76.30668, 73.82273, 76.27298, 76.27825, 68.91329, 76.32396, ...
```

**Edit:**

What leaves me baffled are the oscillations in results of `out2`. Let's remember, our average air temperature is fixed (= 20 °C), so the monthly long term average which is used implicitly, is the same for every month. Accordingly, variability in results between layers should be a function of latitude only, causing some minor spread per layer, but not between layers. But what we actually do have here, is a variability as a function of time, not making sense at all from my point of view, since `tm` is constant.

My careful guess: `SPEI::thornthwaite()` eventually makes assumptions, which are not applicable on this data, so that `out2` is fast but not correct. The results in `out1` seem to have a credible range when comparing results manually making use of the equations given in [Thornthwaite (1948)](https://www.researchgate.net/publication/275605891_Epocas_de_florescimento_e_colheita_da_nogueira-macadamia_para_areas_cafeicolasda_regiao_sudeste/fulltext/55f5a93c08ae63926cf4e732/Epocas-de-florescimento-e-colheita-da-nogueira-macadamia-para-areas-cafeicolasda-regiaeo-sudeste.pdf), eq. 9+10, but don't pin me down on that.